# ¿Como reemplazar caracteres desde una consulta mysql?

Tags: mysql, plsql

Buenas tengo este problema

en la columna de mi tabla `columna1` existen registros basura asi:

```
 564-8953-284/      (785)15479354  juan jose.
```

y lo que quiero son solo los números sin espacios ni `(),./abcdefg...` solo quiero los 10 primeros números había utilizado antes esto

```
SELECT REPLACE(columna,'/','' ) AS campo from mitabla
```

pero ahora ocupo reemplazar varios caracteres de la misma columna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este ejemplo sería algo así:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REPLACE('564-8953-284/ (785)15479354 juan jose','-',''),1,10);
```

Para ampliarlo al resto de caracteres especiales, tendríamos que crear una función equivalente al `REPLACE` pero ampliada:

```
CREATE FUNCTION limpia(str varchar(127))
  RETURNS varchar(127)
  BEGIN
    set str=REPLACE(str,' ','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'-','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'.','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,',','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'(','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,')','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'/','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'a','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'b','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'c','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'d','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'e','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'f','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'g','');
    -- ...
    set str=REPLACE(str,'j','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'u','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'n','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'o','');
    set str=REPLACE(str,'s','');
    RETURN str;
  END;
```

Que llamarías así:

```
SELECT limpia('564-8953-284/ (785)15479354 juan jose');
```

Y con la que obtendrías:

```
5648953284 78515479354
```

En definitiva:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(limpia('564-8953-284/ (785)15479354 juan jose'),1,10);
```

Comment: Del espacio no comentabas nada, si también quieres eliminarlo, no tienes más que añadirlo. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Pruebo y comento, si también los espacios nomas lo añado

Comment: gracias me sirvió perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente yo prefiero otras alternativas a la descrita por @david (muy útil, por cierto).

Prefiero las expresiones regulares. En este caso considero útil las siguientes expresiones.

```
([[:digit:]]{3})-([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{3})/(.*)
```

Esta suponiendo que todos los registros tienen algo de la forma `123-1234-123/demascosas`

O una más general.

```
(.*)/(.*)
```

Y luego añadiendo otra para eliminar lo que no sea un número.

```
[^[[:digit:]]]
```

Suponiendo que puede haber más caracteres indeseables.

El primer caso se ejecutaría algo así:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE('564-8953-284/      (785)15479354  juan jose.',
        '([[:digit:]]{3})-([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{3})/(.*)',
        '$1$2$3'
    ) as resultado;
+------------+
| resultado  |
+------------+
| 5648953284 |
+------------+
```

En el segundo caso.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_REPLACE('564-8953-284/      (785)15479354  juan jose.',
            '(.*)/(.*)',
            '$1'
        ),
        '[^[[:digit:]]]',
        ''
    ) as resultado;
+------------+
| resultado  |
+------------+
| 5648953284 |
+------------+
```

#### Nota importante.

La cuestión de la función `REGEXP_REPLACE` es que está de forma nativa sólo en las versiones de MySQL 8.0+